# Android JSON listview search function(update)

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-filter

1.My search function only works for filter int (ex:rank) if I want to filter char(ex:country name),how should I change this code?

2.When I type something in mEdittext than delete it,the listview become empty,how could I see the json listview again if the mEdittext is empty ?

for now the filter works fine,I just can't figure out how to solve these two question.thanks

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String RANK = "rank";
    static String COUNTRY = "country";
    static String POPULATION = "population";
    static String URL="url";
    static String FLAG = "flag";
    EditText mEditText;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();




        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
        mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayTemplist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    String searchString = mEditText.getText().toString();
                    for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
                        String currentString = arraylist.get(i).get(MainActivity.RANK);
                        if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(currentString)) {
                            arrayTemplist.add(arraylist.get(i));
                        }

                    }
                    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayTemplist);
                    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            }


        });
    }


    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://ndublog.twomini.com/123.txt.txt");

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put("rank", jsonobject.getString("rank"));
                    map.put("country", jsonobject.getString("country"));
                    map.put("population", jsonobject.getString("population"));
                    map.put("url",jsonobject.getString("url"));
                    map.put("flag", jsonobject.getString("flag"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }



        }
```

Comment: It seems that `adapter` is null.

Comment: but the adapter is null?

Comment: try to check `if (MainActivity.this.adapter != null) { ... }`

Comment: or change to : `MainActivity.this.adapter01`. I don't understand why you have a adapter that are always null, and have the adapter01

Answer (score 0):

The filtering has to be done on the listView's adapter, so on onTextChanged, use `adapter01.getFilter().filter(cs);`

Now, for the filtering to work, this adapter has to implement Filterable interface and implement getFilter() method.

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            // publish results here

        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            // Add your filtering code and return results
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

A very good example can be found at the following link: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html

Comment: When I change adapter to adapter01 the getFilter() will be (can not resolve method),so I need to create another java class called ListViewAdapter?

Comment: Your ListViewAdapter needs to implement Filterable and then it should have access to the getFilter method. Like I mentioned, the link has a very well described example.

Comment: The FilterResults says 'android.widget.Filter.FilterResults' has protected access in 'android.widget.Filter'

Comment: It says cannot resolve FilterResults.And I can't import Filter.FilterResults

Answer (score 0):

Change the `adapter` to `adapter01` (the `adapter01` is the one that was initialized)

```
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            MainActivity.this.adapter01.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }
```

For open the site on `ListView`, create a `itemClickListener`:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

       String url = null;
       for (String s : adapter01.getItems()) {
           if (s.hashCode() == id) {
              url = s;
           }
       } 
       Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
       MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);

    }
});
```

And override the `getItemId()` from the adapter.

Example:

```
 protected long getItemId(int position) {
     return getItem(position).hashCode();
 }
```

Comment: When I change adapter to adapter01 the getFilter() will be (can not resolve method)

Comment: Just like @Jayesh said: In your ListView make the class `implements Filterable`

Comment: If I click item after filter the item ,the item position of listview will change ,if I set every single item different url,it will be a wrong website.

Comment: Ok, you can implement the `getItemId` to return a unique has for every position, then get it again.

Comment: I have make the class implements Filterable but still do not works for NullPointerException

Comment: Did you have a sample?

Comment: github.com/EasonWang01/JsonParse/tree/master/app  It's the sample

Comment: But it does not contains your problem. It's hard to analise in this way.

Comment: @YichenWang I think SO it's a good way to ask for answers by your problem, but not for someone implement what you need. In this question, I gave the solution for the item 1 and a path to achieve the item 2. But ask to implement for you it's a little more complicated.

Comment: You're welcome. If one of this answers is enought for you, please mark as correct to support community.

Comment: Is the ArrayAdapter a URL array? Or it's another?